# Select and Count

Tags: select, count

I have a problem with this.

```
select * 
from contract_detail
where contract=264127 
and StartDate >='2014-01-13';
```

I want to select the specific contracts from contract no.264127 going to 264221 with specific dates 2014-01-13 onward?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select * from contract_detail where contract >= 264127 and contract <= 264221 and StartDate >='2014-01-13';
```

Comment: It didn't work. I only need to view contract 264127 to 264221 and date date as stated. It show me also the old data / contracts

Comment: select * from contract_detail where contract >= 264127 and contract < 264221 and StartDate >='2014-01-13'; I removed the = sign. Now I can see them. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you got what you wanted. Just so you know, the < 264221 would not include contracts with contract # 264221. Hopefully that was your intention?